# Proper way to check for memory leaks in Visual C++

Tags: c++, c, arraylist, memory-leaks

I've been trying to improve my own personal C++ skills lately, so I implemented an Array List as a learning exercise.  After I got it working, I started checking for memory leaks, and became very confused by the output.

[Source on GitHub (main.cpp, ArrayList.cpp, ArrayList.h)](https://github.com/CodyIsAwesome/Data-Structures-CPP/tree/master/ArrayList/ArrayList)

I got a lot of information about how to start checking for leaks from [this page
 from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (hence the declarations at the top of the main file, the start of the main function, and the top of the ArrayList.cpp file.

Visual Studio is telling me this information:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
c:\users\cody\desktop\arraylist\arraylist\arraylist.cpp(48) : {4267} normal block at 0x007F9BC8, 3992 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
The program '[16620] ArrayList.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

And the section of code in question

```
void AL::ShrinkToFit()
{
    int* newArray = new int[currentIndexOfFirstOpen]; //Line 48, as mentioned in the mem leak output
    for (int i = 0; i < currentIndexOfFirstOpen; i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = currentArray[i];
    }
    int* oldArray = currentArray;
    currentArray = newArray;
    delete[] oldArray;
    currentMaxLoad = currentIndexOfFirstOpen;
}
```

So clearly I'm missing something.  If you check the ArrayList.cpp file linked above, it (under different circumstances) tells me I have a leak anywhere in that file that I have "new int[some number]".  The page from Microsoft says that I have to use the preprocessor to redefine new because it only works with the C runtime, but it makes no mention of delete (or delete[]).  Is this memory actually being leaked?  I have a matching delete[] for every new[], but I can't tell if it is a legitimate leak or if the leak detecting tools just don't understand delete.  I tried replacing delete with free (I let the preprocessor redefine new as in the Microsoft article), and it made no change.  If I am leaking, can someone point out where/why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run your code with Visual Leak Detector (https://vld.codeplex.com/) and it appears you don't have a memory leak, but when exiting (with the close button) the command prompt the leak detector fails and detects a leak in the line you mentioned. Try deleting this line in the main.cpp

```
Sleep(1000000); //hold the prompt open
```

and put this instead

```
std::cin.get();
return 0;
```

Provide a keystroke at the end of the program and exit with code 0 to the operating system, this should solve your problem.

Comment: It was probably leaking because I was closing the program manually instead of waiting for Sleep(1000000) to execute, so that caused the destructor to not be called.  Thanks for cross checking this for me!